# Jquery Form always submits into new table rather then into kendo window

Tags: jquery, iframe, submit, forms, kendo-window

working on to submit a form from parent view to kendo window iframe view.

Problem I am facing is, when I submit form, it always submits into new window rather then submitting into the popup.

Note: I have set iframe name, id and name of the form into parent view same.

Following is the code that I have wrote so far.

```
KendoWindow.open()
$("#FolderAssistFormID").attr("action", url);
$(KendoWindow.element.find('iframe')[0]).attr("name", "FolderAssistFormIDIF")
$(KendoWindow.element.find('iframe')[0]).attr("id", "FolderAssistFormIDIF");
$('#FolderAssistFormID').attr("target", "FolderAssistFormIDIF");
$('#FolderAssistFormID').trigger("submit");
```

Where KendoWindow is an object of the kendo window, FolderAssistFormID is id of the form, and I have set name and id of the iframe as FolderAssistFormIDIF and also target of the form is set to FolderAssistFormIDIF.

Now, When I submit form **it opens new window**, **when it should follow the target to submit form into kendo window only**.

Please let me know, what I am missing to add.

Thanks

Comment: I have also tried : $('#FolderAssistFormID').on('submit', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.target = 'FolderAssistFormIDIF';
                    this.target = 'FolderAssistFormIDIF';
                    this.submit();
                });

Comment: anyone?........